# Does disableBackgroundDeliveryForType delete the corresponding HKObserverQuery?

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit, hkhealthstore

In HealthKit you create a HKObserverQuery, execute it, and then enableBackgroundDeliveryForType.

```
let backgroundQuery:HKObserverQuery = HKObserverQuery(sampleType: quantityType, predicate: nil) { (query, complete, error) -> Void in
}
self.healthKitStore.executeQuery(backgroundQuery)

self.healthKitStore.enableBackgroundDeliveryForType(
        quantityType,
        frequency: .Immediate,
        withCompletion: { (success, error) -> Void in
            if !success {
                println(error)
            }
    })
```

I'm wondering if I call disableBackgroundDeliveryForType will it just disable the registered HKObserverQuery or will it also delete it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disabling background delivery won't stop the observer query.  It only prevents your app from being resumed in the background to be informed about new samples.  When your app is in the foreground, your observer query's `updateHandler` will continue to execute when there is new data.  You must call `HKHealthStore.stopQuery(backgroundQuery)` to stop it.

Comment: Allan, what is the lifetime of an HKObserverQuery? When should it be stopped and recreated ?

Comment: The lifetime is as long as you want it to be.  Once you start it, it runs until you explicitly stop it or your app exits.  You should explicitly stop it whenever you no longer need the updates it provides.

Comment: Thanks thats good to know, another question though: so when my app gets launched by the background delivery after being terminated and I recreate my observer query in the applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions. 
Any ideas on why afterwards when the user reopens the app manually, the updateHandler gets called an amount of times similar to the amount of times my app was launched in the background?

Comment: That sounds like a bug you should file with Apple.